# How to load cached requests with AFNetworking 2.0 if app is reopen?

Tags: ios, caching, afnetworking, nsurl, nsurlcache

I have been using AFNetworking 2.0. Cache works well if the app is in foreground, or came from background. But when I kill the app and reopen it, cache is cleared. Is there a way to make it persistent? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can cache from disk using the **NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad cache policy**:

Objective-c

```
NSURLRequest *imageRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]
                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad    
                                          timeoutInterval:60];

[imageView setImageWithURLRequest:imageRequest
                 placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]
                          success:nil
                          failure:nil];
```

Swift

```
let imageRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL.URLWithString(imageUrl), 
                        cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReturnCacheDataElseLoad, 
                    timeoutInterval: 60)

imageView.setImageWithURLRequest(imageRequest, 
                             placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"), 
                                      success: nil, 
                                      failure: nil)
```

Source: [here](http://www.overacker.me/blog/2015/01/12/image-caching-with-afnetworking)